# How to retain the data in ListView without using Database in VB6

Tags: listview, vb6

Is it possible to retain the data listed in `ListView` without using `Database`? I am using `VB6` and I want to retain the data I listed in listview even if the users re-open the program. If its possible, how can I do that?

Comment: Just save the data, and reload it.

Comment: is it vb6 or .net ? do you mean ListBox ? If it is ListBox, enter each item in the design mode for the LIst property of ListBox, by using Ctrl+Enter for every entry in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use a database to store data outside of an application.

The best way would probably be to store it in a simple text file. I would use the built-in VB file access statements - `Write #` to save to the file, and `Input #` to load the data in.

You could also use the `MSXML` library to persist it as XML, although this is overkill.

If it was small amounts of data, you could store it in the registry using the `SaveSetting`/`GetSetting` functions.

Comment: Or another option might be a fabricated ADO Recordset, which supports Save and Load methods.  Or I suppose you could use INI files with each "row" or item as a separate Section, or JSON if you use one of many JSON libraries, etc.  But simple text is often just fine.

Comment: thanks @Mark. I already think about that and tried it and it works :)